# Pausing program until the response is obtained

Tags: windows-phone-7, ip-address, webclient

```
static string IP_Address = "";
getIPAddress();
MessageBox.Show(IP_Address);
```

My function is like this:

```
 public static void getIPAddress()
 {
    Uri uri = new Uri("http://whatismyip.org", UriKind.Absolute);
    WebClient client = new WebClient();

    client.DownloadStringCompleted += (s, e) =>
        {
            var res = e.Result;
            IP_Address = res;
        };
    client.DownloadStringAsync(uri);
 }
```

I am using this code to set the IP Address of my client. But the problem is that, when I run the code, at first the empty string of IP_Address in displayed then only

```
client.DownloadStringCompleted += (s, e) =>
        {
            var res = e.Result;
            IP_Address = res;
        };
```

part is executed. Any suggestions to run the above code block before the IP_Address is displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 getIPAddress((ip) =>
 {
      MessageBox.Show(ip);
 });
```

.

```
 public static void getIPAddress(Action<string> callback)
 {
      Uri uri = new Uri("http://whatismyip.org", UriKind.Absolute);
      WebClient client = new WebClient();

      client.DownloadStringCompleted += (s, e) =>
      {
           var res = e.Result;

           callback(res);
      };
      client.DownloadStringAsync(uri);
 }
```